# Is the language used in this paragraph very intelligible for a native speaker?

Tags: sentence-meaning

this is an excerpt from "Euclid's Elements"

*"A straight line is said to have been cut in extreme and mean ratio* **when, **as the**** *whole line is to the greater segment, so is the greater to the lesser."*

I translated this paragraph to Polish using Chat Gdp. This is the answer it returned and which I paraphrased in English:

"*A straight line is said to have been cut in extreme and mean ratio* **when the ratio** *of the whole line and the greater segment, is the* *same* **as the ratio** *of the greater line and the lesser."*

When stated like that I get what it means but I don't understand the way it was put in the context. Is this just because it's written in obsolete language? **Is it easy to read for a native person?**

Comment: That is an excerpt from a translation from the Greek where is the English is old fashioned. Do try avoiding automated translation programs. They are never very good.

Comment: Or, it's a translation of the Latin, which is a translation of the Arabic, which is a translation of the Greek, of language in which the writer was more concerned to be precise and unambiguous, rather than easily understood... into old fashioned English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not how a geometry book would be written today, but it's not that hard to read if I think about it for a few seconds.

Back when I took it, the SAT (an American college entrance exam used by a large number of schools) had a section of logical "analogies" that used a similar structure, so we drilled on understanding it. The fact that they needed to provide those drills is a sign that for a lot of students the structure didn't come naturally and they had to study to learn to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the language is not very clear to a native English speaker. It's a translation from Greek to English, which often results in awkward sentences. And on top of that it's a very technical subject, which can be difficult to understand even if written by a native speaker who is a skilled writer.

But yes, the intended meaning is that the two ratios are the same. If the length of the whole line is X, and then we mark off a piece of this line as Y, then what's left must be X-Y. Then X/Y = Y/(X-Y).

Comment: I think the most important part of the answer is buried in your second paragraph: we have created a completely new language for talking about these things, which is the language of symbolic mathematics. This language didn't exist when Euclid wrote his *Elements*. What Euclid is describing here is the *Golden Ratio* (which we ironically nowadays denote by the Greek letter Φ), and what he is essentially saying is that Φ is the solution to the equation a/b = (a + b)/a, except that the idea of using symbols to denote mathematical objects hadn't been invented yet.

Comment: So, I am not sure the reason why it is hard to understand is because it is translated from Greek, but rather that we are not used to reading mathematics described this way, and haven't been for 600 years.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Both. Texts translated from other languages are often hard to read. Texts on technical subjects are often hard to read. And as you pointed out, since Euclid's time better ways to express mathematical ideas have come along, like the use of standard symbols rather than trying to describe a concept with words.